# Docker compose - port forward from host IP to specific IP in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container that sits in multiple networks, and specifically two "external" networks.

The host also has two NICs and I need to forward from one host IP to a specific IP on the container, and then forward the other host IP to the other IP on the container.

For example, take this docker compose segment:

```
services:
  server:
    image: image
    networks:
      internal_net:
        ipv4_address: 1.0.0.1
      ext1_net:
        ipv4_address: 1.1.1.1
      ext2_net:
        ipv4_address: 2.2.2.2
```

And say on the host on eth0 I have 3.3.3.3 and on eth1 I have 4.4.4.4

I would then want to forward 80 from 3.3.3.3 on the host to 1.1.1.1 on the container,
I would then want to forward 80 from 4.4.4.4 on the host to 2.2.2.2 on the container

However, the ports option doesn't seem to allow forwarding to a specific container interface.

How do I achieve this? Do I need to do the iptables rules manually?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Docker sets up the forwarding rule to publish a container port on the host, it looks like it always chooses the address of the first interface. So given a configuration like this:

```
services:
  server:
    image: image
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      internal_net:
        ipv4_address: 1.0.0.1
      ext1_net:
        ipv4_address: 1.1.1.1
      ext2_net:
        ipv4_address: 2.2.2.2
```

Docker would create something like this rule in the `nat` table:

```
-A DOCKER ! -i br-439dfcc4c0d7 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.0.0.1:8080
```

If you wanted to explicitly target a different address, you would
exclude the `ports` entry from your `docker-compose.yaml` and
add your own rules to the `PREROUTING` chain of the `nat` table.
For example:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination
1.1.1.1:8080
```

Communication *from* your container back to your host is going to be
governed by the routing table inside the container. Typically, the
default route will be via `eth0`, so your container will not
necessarily reply over the interface you expect. Because Docker
creates `MASQUERADE` rules for all the addresses in your container
this should not be a problem.